# Appium IOSDriver.swipe doesn't work anymore?

Tags: ios, automated-tests, appium, swipe, appium-ios

I'm used to swipe from right to left with this code:

```
appiumDriver.context("NATIVE_APP");
Dimension size = appiumDriver.manage().window().getSize();
int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.8);
int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.20);
int starty = size.height / 2;
appiumDriver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 500);
```

It's supposed to swipe from right to left, and it worked just fine before (I have a CI for this). But now it doesn't work anymore, and I see that when I run the test on real device, it swipes from left to right!

Does anyone know if the swipe of this method is not supported anymore? And if there is any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any sort of exception or crash occurring? This could potentially be due to the iOS magnifying glass appearing. If this is the issue you can fix it via decreasing the `duration` argument withing the `swipe`  method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes appiumDriver do not support this method now, not sure why.

Below code is working for me, you can give it a try, touchShortcuts actually do the magic here.

((TouchShortcuts) driver).swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 500);

Comment: thanks for your reply, But TouchShortcuts doesn't work for me (there is a warning:  Casting 'appiumDriver' to 'TouchShortcuts' is redundant). It still swipes from left to right, and not full swipe.

Comment: In your code point x is always going to be less and y greater so , it will swipe from left to right only. please change the multiplication part to be opposite i.e. int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.20);
int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.8);  please give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the follow up. I changed my code as follow appiumDriver.swipe(startx, starty, -(startx - 20), starty, 1000); and it does the work. In Appium server logs, swipe method was changed, so I changed my code too accordingly

Comment: great, happy to hear that :)